# Using subscript in easylist numbering

Tags: numbering, subscripts, easylist

I just wanted to add a small issue I encountered with the use of easylists and subscript.
Using **easylist**, I had an issue with my parenthesis appearing with **subscript** style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}
    \ListProperties(Style*={(H\textsubscript}, % i want my numbering to be (H\textsubscript{numbers})
        Mark={}, % no markings
        Numbers1=l, % level 1 are letters
        Numbers2=a, % level 2 are numbers
        Progressive=1em, % progressive margin 1em
        FinalMark={)} ) % this is where i put my parenthesis
    & I am sad
    && because the parenthesis appears as subscript
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Issue with bad parenthesis]

Comment: Please post a compilable document, i.e. with `\documentclass... \begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @DaiBowen: I think the post isn't a question but a solution already.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you for the first instructions, they were very helpful (for me as a beginner on this site). The goal was to provide a trace of the issue so anyone having it might find an answer.

Comment: @Lokinou: I think you should restate your post as a question and post your solution in the answer box below. You can 'self-accept' your own - solution then

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer (and DaiBowen) for the great help in solving my issues

Answer (score 3):

The value for the `Style` key can be a macro expecting an argument. Just put in it also the parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\newcommand{\mynumbering}[2]{%
  (#1\textsubscript{#2})%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}
    \ListProperties(Style*={\mynumbering{H}},
        Mark={}, % no markings
        Numbers1=l, % level 1 are letters
        Numbers2=a, % level 2 are numbers
        Progressive=1em, % progressive margin 1em
    )
    & I am happy
    && because the parentheses are right
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this issue: I created a small command that wraps the current numbering after the subscript "brackets" ends:

```
\newcommand{\addpar}[1]{#1)} % adds a parenthesis ) after #1
```

Lets try again

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\addpar}[1]{#1)} % adds a parenthesis ) after #1

\begin{easylist}
    \ListProperties(Style*={(H\textsubscript}, % i want my numbering to be (H\textsubscript{numbers})
    Mark={}, % no markings
    Numbers1=l, % level 1 are letters
    Numbers2=a, % level 2 are numbers
    Progressive=1em, % progressive margin 1em
    FinalMark={}, % do not forget to remove it here
    CtrCom=\addpar) %my little custom command will wraps the numbering, adding a parenthesis at the end
    & I am happy
    && because the parenthesis appears with the correct size
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

Correct output:
[image: Correct output with parenthesis]